# i am creating stacked+line chart,with custom data set,but showingmany extra horizontal grid lines

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[image]

i have achieved everything except three things:

1. first i want show dotted line from bar two last bar.
2. I want to hide extra horizontal lines
3. I want to hide first two scales in y-axis (left),i want to show only title and thousandK values

https://codepen.io/ali227786/pen/mdazRgR

See my reference image

```js
// Custom function to return triangle caret point style
function customPointStyle(context) {
  const value = context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex];
  if (value >= 0) {
    // Display an upward-pointing triangle caret for positive values
    return "triangle";
  } else {
    // Display a downward-pointing triangle caret for negative values
    return "rectRot";
  }
}

var ebitdaData = [51741, 58854, 52828, 33500, 52313];
var maxEbitda = Math.max(...ebitdaData);

// Calculate the maximum value for y-axis-1 (right y-axis)
var maxAxis1 = Math.ceil(maxEbitda / 1000) * 1000; // Round up to the nearest thousand
var stepSizeAxis1 = maxAxis1 / 6; // Divide into 6 steps
var yaxisdata = [
  "-80000",
  "0",
  "80000",
  "160000",
  "240000",
  "320000",
  "400000",
];
var yaxisdataRight = [
  "30000",
  "35000",
  "40000",
  "45000",
  "50000",
  "55000",
  "60000",
];

// Define the chart data
var chartData = {
  labels: ["Jan 2018", "Jan 2019", "Jan 2020", "Jan 2021", "Jan 2022"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Other Expenses",
      yAxisID: "y-axis-2",
      backgroundColor: "#0EAA7E",
      stack: "expenses-stack",
      data: [46789, 50530, 48249, 50372, 64055],
      order: 2,
    },
    {
      label: "Employee Benefits Expenses",
      yAxisID: "y-axis-2",
      backgroundColor: "#00127B",
      stack: "expenses-stack",
      data: [4740, 5834, 6067, 5024, 5426],
      order: 2,
    },
    {
      label: "Change in Inventory and Finished Goods",
      yAxisID: "y-axis-2",
      backgroundColor: "#133A35",
      stack: "expenses-stack",
      data: [-3232, -3294, 77, 610, -7962],
      order: 2,
    },
    {
      label: "Purchases of Stock",
      yAxisID: "y-axis-2",
      backgroundColor: "#62A8BB",
      stack: "expenses-stack",
      data: [7268, 8289, 7292, 7301, 10691],
      order: 2,
    },
    {
      label: "Cost of Material Consumed",
      yAxisID: "y-axis-2",
      backgroundColor: "#286373",
      stack: "expenses-stack",
      data: [198029, 265288, 237342, 168262, 320852],
      order: 2,
    },
    {
      label: "Ebdita",
      yAxisID: "y-axis-1",
      backgroundColor: "#E04C2B",
      borderColor: "#E04C2B",
      type: "line",
      fill: false,
      data: ebitdaData,
      order: 1,
      pointStyle: customPointStyle,
      datalabels: {
        color: "black",
        align: "top",
        anchor: "center",
      },
    },
  ],
};

var maxAxis1 = Math.max(
  ...chartData.datasets
    .filter((dataset) => dataset.yAxisID === "y-axis-2")
    .map((dataset) => Math.max(...dataset.data))
);

// Round up to the nearest thousand
var maxAxis1Rounded = Math.ceil(maxAxis1 / 1000) * 1000;

var chartOptions = {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false, // Hide the default legend
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Operating Cost V/s EBITDA",
      font: {
        size: 18,
        weight: "bold",
      },
    },
    datalabels: {
      color: "white",
      align: "center",
      anchor: "center",
      font: {
        weight: "bold",
      },
      formatter: function (value, context) {
        return (value / 1000).toFixed(0) + "K";
      },
    },
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
      display: true,
      grid: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
    y: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: ["Breakdown of Operating Expenses", "(INR Cr)"],
        font: {
          weight: "bold",
          size: 18,
        },
      },
      beginAtZero: true,
      position: "left",
      max: maxAxis1Rounded,
      ticks: {
        stepSize: 55555,
        callback: function (value, index, values) {
          return (yaxisdata[index] / 1000).toFixed(0) + "K";
        },
        drawBorder: false,
      },
      grid: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
    y2: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "EBITDA (INR Cr) ",
        font: {
          weight: "bold",
          size: 18,
        },
      },
      beginAtZero: true,
      position: "right",
      max: 60000,
      id: "y-axis-ebdita",
      ticks: {
        callback: function (value, index, values) {
          return (yaxisdataRight[index] / 1000).toFixed(0) + "K";
        },
        drawBorder: false,
      },
      grid: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
    y1: {
      display: false,
    },
  },
};

Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
//Chart.defaults.datasets.radar.showLine = false;
Chart.defaults.showLine.display = false;
// Create custom legends for the left and right sides
const legendLeft = document.getElementById("legend-left");
const legendRight = document.getElementById("legend-right");

chartData.datasets.forEach((dataset, index) => {
  const listItem = document.createElement("li");
  listItem.innerHTML = `
    <span class="legend-color" style="background-color:${dataset.backgroundColor}"></span>
    <span class="legend-label">${dataset.label}</span>
  `;
  listItem.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(index);
    meta.hidden =
      meta.hidden === null ? !chart.data.datasets[index].hidden : null;
    chart.update();
  });

  if (index < chartData.datasets.length / 2) {
    // Add to the left legend
    legendLeft.appendChild(listItem);
  } else {
    // Add to the right legend
    legendRight.appendChild(listItem);
  }
});

// Initialize the chart
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "bar",
  data: chartData,
  options: chartOptions,
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Chart.js Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.0.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/1.0.2/chartjs-plugin-annotation.js"></script>
    <style>
      /* CSS styles for the legend container and lists */
      .legend-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        max-width: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      .legend-list {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: 20px;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        gap: 10px;
      }

      .legend-list li {
        cursor: pointer;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 10px); /* Three columns with 10px gap */
      }

      .legend-color {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        margin-right: 5px;
        border-radius: 50%;
      }

      .legend-label {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="max-width: 75%; margin: 0 auto">
      <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
      <div class="legend-container">
        <ul id="legend-left" class="legend-list"></ul>
        <ul id="legend-right" class="legend-list"></ul>
      </div>
      <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.